# Error while saving in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am getting forllowing error when I try to save data in to MngoDB. `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:481:11)`
It was working fine, I do not know from where this error came from! I have tried to install and unistall jest, as suggested, not useful.
here is when the error happens:

```js
            dataTrattamenti.save((error) => {

                if (error) {
                   
                    res.send({success: false, message: 'We cannot save the data, there is an error: ', error})
                } else
                  
                res.send({success: true, message: 'Successfully saved'})
            });
```

if I write

```js
   res.end({success: true, message: 'Successfully saved'})
```

as suggested by some, i am not getting any error in Node but in what it send is

```js
 'We cannot save the data, there is an error:
```

while error variable seems to be empty.
I tryied the code with postman, it works fine. please help, I have no clue what is going on. what is the header the error is talking about?

Comment: The error means you have already call "res.send" somewhere in your code. Then you can't call "send" again.

Comment: for that post function, I have tow res.send which are in the body of if. I am wondering why all of a sudden it starts to catch this error.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have logged the error message seperately, since in the folliwing code, it would not log anything as error, what I got was, this message only `We cannot save the data, there is an error:`

```js
res.send({success: false, message: 'We cannot save the data, there is an error: ', error})
```

Then, I saw that the error is not about header, but a duplication error in the database. SO i got it solved.